# remove xy term from quadratic, using eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Use the eigenvalue and eigenvector procedure to eliminate the term crossing $xy$ in the quadratic $4x^2+16xy+13y^2=8$
Determine the nature of the conic it represents and draw its graph on the transformed system.

the associated matrix is
$\left(x,y\right)\begin{pmatrix}{4}&{8}\\{8}&{13}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix} =8$

the values and eigenvectors of the matrix are

$ \lambda _1 = \frac{-\sqrt{337}+17}{2}$
$ \lambda _2 = \frac{\sqrt{337}+17}{2}$
eigenvectors
$v1 = ( \frac{\sqrt{337}+9}{16}, 1)$
$ v2= ( \frac{\sqrt{337}+9}{16}, 1 )$
are the values and eigenvectors of the matrix correct? How can I simplify them? I need help to finish the exercise and identify the conic please.

Comment: 2 eigenvalues with opposite signs gives a hyperbola. You can  be convinced of it by writing the equation of your conic under the form $(2x+4y)^2-3y^2=8$, i.e., up to a linear transformation, $X^2-3Y^2=8$. It is an hyperbola.

Comment: thanks for answering, these values that I have obtained are correct, I need help to be able to finish the exercise by using values and eigenvectors, what are the steps that follow? please help me

Comment: If your initial matrix is $Q$, $P:=[v_1,v_2]$ (in columns), and $D:=diag(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$, you can replace $Q$ by $PDP^{-1}$. Remark: It is strange that your values are so complicated. Check may be your initial data.

Answer (score 1):

Because the matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 8 \\ 8 & 13 \end{pmatrix}$ is symmetric, the eigenvectors are orthogonal. It is trivial to parametrize the orthogonal matrix in 2D

$${\rm R} = \pmatrix{\cos \psi & -\sin \psi \\ \sin \psi & \cos \psi} $$

where the columns are the eigenvectors.

The eigenvalues $\lambda_1$  and $\lambda_2$ form the diagonal matrix $D$ such that

$$ A = {\rm R}\, D\, {\rm R}^\top $$

From the elements of the above you have $$\begin{aligned} 
4 & =  -\frac{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1}{2} \cos 2\psi + \frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}{2} \\ 13 & =  \frac{\lambda_2 - \lambda_1}{2} \cos 2\psi + \frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}{2} \\
8 & = -\frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}{2} \sin 2\psi
\end{aligned}$$

which you subtract the 2nd from the 1st and divide by the 3rd to get

$$ \left. \frac{9}{8} = -\frac{1}{2} \tan(2\psi) \right\}\;\;\; \psi = \frac{1}{2} {\rm atan} \left( \frac{9}{16} \right) - \frac{\pi}{4} $$

And plug this into the first two equations above to get

$$\left. \begin{aligned}
4 & = -\frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}{2} \sin\left( {\rm atan}(\tfrac{9}{16}) \right) + \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2} \\
13 & = \frac{\lambda_2-\lambda_1}{2} \sin \left( {\rm atan}(\tfrac{9}{16}) \right) + \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}
\end{aligned} \right\} \;\;\; \begin{aligned} \lambda_1 & = \frac{17}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{337}}{2} \\ 
\lambda_2 & = \frac{17}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{337}}{2} \end{aligned}  $$

providing the following decomposition matrices

$$\begin{aligned}D & =\begin{pmatrix}\frac{17}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2} & 0\\
0 & \frac{17}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}
\end{pmatrix} & {\rm R} & =\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{2\sqrt{337}}} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{2\sqrt{337}}}\\
-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{2\sqrt{337}}} & \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{2\sqrt{337}}}
\end{pmatrix}\end{aligned}$$

---

The original problem is

$${\rm x}^{\top}A\,{\rm x}=b$$

where ${\rm x} = \pmatrix{x \\ y}$, $b = 8$ and $A$ as above.

Now we do a change of variables such that ${\rm x} = {\rm R}\, {\rm u}$ where ${\rm u} = \pmatrix{u \\ v}$ to arrive at

$$ {\rm u}^\top \left( {\rm R}^\top A \,{\rm R} \right) {\rm u} = b $$ and recognize that $D = {\rm R}^\top A \,{\rm R}$ since ${\rm R}^{-1} = {\rm R}^\top$

So the problem is now diagonalized into ${\rm u}^\top D\, {\rm u} = b$ or expanded out to

$$u^{2}\left(\frac{17}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}\right)+v^{2}\left(\frac{17}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}\right)=8$$

The above can be factored into

$$\left(v\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}+\tfrac{17}{2}}\right)^{2}-\left(u\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}-\tfrac{17}{2}}\right)^{2} =8 $$

and by using the identity $x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)$ the following two factors exist

$$\left(v\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}+\tfrac{17}{2}}-u\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}-\tfrac{17}{2}}\right)\left(v\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}+\tfrac{17}{2}}+u\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}-\tfrac{17}{2}}\right)=8$$

These two factors are the equations for the cone

$$ \begin{aligned} v\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}+\tfrac{17}{2}}-u\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}-\tfrac{17}{2}} & = 0 \\ v\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}+\tfrac{17}{2}}+u\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{337}}{2}-\tfrac{17}{2}} & = 0 \end{aligned}$$

Finally, reverse the change of variables with ${\rm u} = {\rm R}^\top {\rm x}$ which corresponds to

$$ \small \begin{aligned}u & =x\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{2\sqrt{337}}}-y\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{2\sqrt{337}}}\\
v & =x\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{9}{2\sqrt{337}}}+y\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{9}{2\sqrt{337}}}
\end{aligned} $$

To get the lines defining the cone as

$$ \begin{aligned}x\sqrt{\frac{92}{\sqrt{337}}+\frac{32\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{336}}}+y\sqrt{\frac{245}{\sqrt{337}}-\frac{32\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{336}}} & =0\\
x\sqrt{\frac{92}{\sqrt{337}}-\frac{32\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{336}}}+y\sqrt{\frac{245}{\sqrt{337}}+\frac{32\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{336}}} & =0
\end{aligned} $$